# JavaScript function not overriding variable

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have this code below:

```
function searchQuery() {
  var r = 'toReplace';
  chrome.storage.sync.get(['search_query'], function(result) {
    console.log(result.search_query);
    r = result.search_query;
  });
  return r;
}
```

I console.log this function somewhere else, and the console.log inside the sync.get function outputs the right thing, but the function itself is "toReplace." Why is this?

Comment: `storage.sync` doesn't appear to be synchronous. The `sync` stands for _"synchronize"_

Answer (score 2):

As @Phil said, the call is most likely asynchronous. I'd recommend looking at using the [async & await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) syntax.